# How can you power on and off devices via GPIO

Tags: python

I have a humidity sensor monitoring but I only want it to monitor for a short time and then I want to power it off. It is 3.3v. I am using CRON to call a script.py When the script finishes I would like power cut to the device.  I am assuming I would use another GPIO to do this but I wanted to see if there are other ways?

Is it as simple as either hooking the 3.3v pin or ground PIN to another GPIO?
Thanks!

Comment: What sensor?  What are the sensor's power requirements? `Please edit this information into your question.`

Comment: Why do you want the power cut to the device?

Comment: long periods of inactive times and dont need extra wear on the device.

Comment: @OblongMedulla Note that if you are using a DHTXX (DHT11, DHT22 etc) you will have to make two readings and discard the first if it is powered down then up.  The first reading after power up is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the sensor can be powered from 3V3 and the sensor requires less than 16mA**

Power the sensor with a GPIO.  Set the GPIO to 1 to switch the sensor on.  Set the GPIO to 0 to switch the sensor off.

**If the sensor can't be powered from 3V3 or the sensor requires more than 16mA**

Power the sensor with a transistor or relay controlled by a GPIO.  Set the GPIO to 1 to switch the sensor on.  Set the GPIO to 0 to switch the sensor off.

Comment: Thanks Joan! I just wanted to be sure before I brink the Pi, or maybe was a better way!

Comment: GPIO pins can sink up to 16mA, but how much can they source?

Comment: @PetrusTheron A Pi GPIO can source/sink 16mA.  However it's suggested you don't source/sink more than 50mA from the GPIO as a whole.